# Как узнать количество элементов в переменной POST?

Tags: php

Есть форма, которую менять нельзя.
Она передает переменные в POST.
Пример

```
array(20) { ["posted"]=> string(4) "true" ["platel"]=> string(4) "test" ["address"]=> string(24) "Tomsk Vershinina 39a 527" ["mobil"]=> string(1) "1" ["email"]=> string(17) "votanko@gmail.com"  
["goods1"]=> string(8) "product1" ["kod1"]=> string(6) "634000" ["qantity1"]=> string(2) "10" ["price1"]=> string(4)  
 "1000" ["comments1"]=> string(3) "Red" ["goods2"]=> string(8) "product2" ["kod2"]=> string(6) "634000" ["qantity2"]=> string(2) "20" ["price2"]=> string(4) "2000" ["comments2"]=> string(4) "Blue"   
["dostavka"]=> string(1) "1" ["transport_kompaniya"]=> string(0) "" ["moskaw_address"]=> string(0) "" ["oplata"]=> string(1) "1" ["Submit"]=> string(9) "Отправить" }
```

Как можно узнать количество всех элементов категории  $_POST['goods'].
Т.е в этом примере их два $_POST['goods1'] $_POST['goods2']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исходя из похожих вопросов [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173804/using-array-key-exists-with-preg-match) и [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12482388/php-finding-keys-in-an-array-that-match-a-pattern):

1. С помощью `foreach` проходим по массиву `$_POST` и с помощью `preg_match` проверяем подходит ли условию ключ:

   ```
   $count = 0;
   foreach (array_keys($_POST) as $k) {
       if (preg_match('/^goods(\d+)$/', $k, $matches)) {
           $count++;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Получаем все ключи с помощью array_keys и находим те, которые соответствуют шаблону с помощью preg_grep:

   ```
   $keysAll = array_keys($_POST);
   $keysPattern = preg_grep('/^goods(\d+)$/', $keysAll);
   $count = count($keysPattern);
   ```

Comment: Спасибо. Помогло.

Comment: переборку же нельзя сделать ?
$_POST['goods1'] $_POST['goods0'] $_POST['goods2'] $_POST['goods3'] в пхп же нет такой штуки чтобы подставлять цифры

Comment: @votanko, почему нет ? в цикле "goods{$id}" например, а $id меняется.  или что имеется ввиду?

Comment: $_POST['goods{$id}']  - т.е вот так?

Comment: @votanko, $_POST["goods{$id}"], в двойных надо, если с подстановкой переменных.

Comment: спасибо - буду иметь ввиду.